# How to retrieve all the comments on feed/posts with facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So far, I have tried calling this: `me/feed?fields=id,comments.summary(true)&limit=100` from my http only website and [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) with access token present from both

But I only get comments written by me

Example response with comment count equal to 2 but actual array of comments has only my comment:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "...",
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "created_time": "2021-04-20T14:29:54+0000",
            "from": {
              "name": "my name",
              "id": "my id"
            },
            "message": "....",
            "id": "commentId"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "before": "...",
            "after": "..."
          }
        },
        "summary": {
          "order": "chronological",
          "total_count": 2,
          "can_comment": true
        }
      }
    },
  ],
"paging": {
    "previous": "...",
    "next": "..."
  }
}
```

Same thing with `/post_id/comments` and `/me/posts?fields=id,comments.summary(true)&limit=100`

Is there a way to get all the comments (not only ones written by current user) on feed/posts with facebook graph api?